# call mysql procedure using PDO got general error

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

Hello i have question about PDO, i have a mysql procedure like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `user_regis`(IN `name` VARCHAR(50), IN `hp` VARCHAR(12), IN `email` VARCHAR(30), IN `username` VARCHAR(20), IN `password  VARCHAR(20) )

    BEGIN

        IF (SELECT NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USER_USERNAME = username AND USER_EMAIL = email)) THEN

            INSERT INTO USER
              (USER_ID, USER_NAME, USER_HP, USER_EMAIL, USER_USERNAME, USER_PASSWORD) 
            VALUES 
              (null,name,hp,email,username,password) ;

            INSERT INTO `VOUCHER`(`VOUCHER_CODE`, `USER_USERNAME`, `VOUCER_STATUS`, `VOUCHER_EXPIRY`) 
            VALUES((SELECT CONCAT('TRVL',ROUND(RAND()*1000000))),username,1,(SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 48 HOUR) ) ;

            SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USER_USERNAME = username ;

        END IF;

    END
```

and then i call my procedure using PDO :

```
$regis = $this->pdo->query('call user_regis(a,a,a,a,a)');
if($regis->fetchColumn > 0){ echo "hai" ; }
```

but i got an error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in

can someone explain me why ?
thanks for your help

Comment: doesn't look like the stored procedure returns anything if the `IF` condition is not met.  Is that possibly the case?

Comment: can mysql return zero result making pdo error ? @DanFarrell

Comment: It's hard to say, since you didn't provide a complete example.  I'm not sure.

Comment: i was try to inserting data using parameter to my procedure using pdo->query(call user_regis(a,a,a,a,a)  ); for the first time it work but after that i got an error  like i said before @DanFarrell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our conversation in comments, I think you should move the `SELECT` down below the `END IF` line so it's executed regardless of whether the `IF` condition is met.

You'll also have to provide whatever required parameters to the stored procedure.

Comment: But you only did half of what I told you to.

Comment: you're right, it's something wrong with IF condition in my mysql procedure, so I removed it and used IF condition in PHP, thank your very much :)